# How can I find nodes with specific values that are in specific range?

Tags: memgraphdb

How can I find nodes with specific properties using a Cypher query language? I have a list of cities. List contains city names and population. I need to print out names of all cities that have population between two defined values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match nodes with properties in a range use the following code:

```
MATCH (c:City)
WHERE c.population_size >= 1000000 AND c.population_size <= 2000000
RETURN c;
```